why administrator user on msys2_sshd got permission denied when tried to install wsl?
I have setup a ssh server on Windows 11 to be able remotely using it while I'm away from the computer, and now I tried to install wsl through ssh, the following cmd prompt and msys2 shell output is executed from ssh session:
C:\msys64\home\user\gsudo.portable\x64>C:\Windows\System32\whoami.exe /all

USER INFORMATION
----------------

User Name SID
========= ==============================================
ryuu\user S-1-5-21-3433435007-3109692699-4129412338-1001


GROUP INFORMATION
-----------------

Group Name                                                    Type             SID          Attributes
============================================================= ================ ============ ===============================================================
Everyone                                                      Well-known group S-1-1-0      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Local account and member of Administrators group Well-known group S-1-5-114    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Administrators                                        Alias            S-1-5-32-544 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group, Group owner
BUILTIN\Users                                                 Alias            S-1-5-32-545 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE                                      Well-known group S-1-5-4      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
CONSOLE LOGON                                                 Well-known group S-1-2-1      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users                              Well-known group S-1-5-11     Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization                                Well-known group S-1-5-15     Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Local account                                    Well-known group S-1-5-113    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\NTLM Authentication                              Well-known group S-1-5-64-10  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level                          Label            S-1-16-12288


PRIVILEGES INFORMATION
----------------------

Privilege Name                            Description                                                        State
========================================= ================================================================== ========
SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege                  Adjust memory quotas for a process                                 Disabled
SeSecurityPrivilege                       Manage auditing and security log                                   Disabled
SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege                  Take ownership of files or other objects                           Disabled
SeLoadDriverPrivilege                     Load and unload device drivers                                     Disabled
SeSystemProfilePrivilege                  Profile system performance                                         Disabled
SeSystemtimePrivilege                     Change the system time                                             Disabled
SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege           Profile single process                                             Disabled
SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege           Increase scheduling priority                                       Disabled
SeCreatePagefilePrivilege                 Create a pagefile                                                  Disabled
SeBackupPrivilege                         Back up files and directories                                      Enabled
SeRestorePrivilege                        Restore files and directories                                      Enabled
SeShutdownPrivilege                       Shut down the system                                               Disabled
SeDebugPrivilege                          Debug programs                                                     Enabled
SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege              Modify firmware environment values                                 Disabled
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege                   Bypass traverse checking                                           Enabled
SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege                 Force shutdown from a remote system                                Disabled
SeUndockPrivilege                         Remove computer from docking station                               Disabled
SeManageVolumePrivilege                   Perform volume maintenance tasks                                   Disabled
SeImpersonatePrivilege                    Impersonate a client after authentication                          Enabled
SeCreateGlobalPrivilege                   Create global objects                                              Enabled
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege             Increase a process working set                                     Disabled
SeTimeZonePrivilege                       Change the time zone                                               Disabled
SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege             Create symbolic links                                              Disabled
SeDelegateSessionUserImpersonatePrivilege Obtain an impersonation token for another user in the same session Disabled

#  accesschk -accepteula -p sshd

Accesschk v6.15 - Reports effective permissions for securable objects
Copyright (C) 2006-2022 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

[3284] sshd.exe
  RW NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
     NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
  RW BUILTIN\Administrators
[6572] sshd-session.exe
  RW NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
     NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
  RW BUILTIN\Administrators
[7004] sshd-session.exe
  RW NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
     NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
  RW BUILTIN\Administrators
# /c/Windows/System32/whoami.exe
ryuu\user
# gsudo -s wsl --install
      6 [main] bash (10724) cygheap_user::init: NtSetInformationToken (TokenDefaultDacl), 0xC0000022
Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

from the output above, it shows that the sshd is running as administrator (not sure though) and the msys terminal show # instead of $ which indicate it running as root/administrator, however the whoami command show that the ssh session is running as regular user, is there a way to workaround the permission issue without uac (as it's not possible to interact with it in ssh connection)?
I tried portable gsudo using -s option to instruct it to run as Local System account and it seems not working properly
